# Error when trying to create stored procedure db2

Tags: sql, db2

This is what I've entered to create a stored procedure that displays details from customers where cus_ID = CustomerID parameter.

```
Create procedure getCusDetails (IN CustomerID int) \
BEGIN \
DECLARE c cursor with return for \
SELECT *from customer \
where cus_ID = CustomerID \
OPEN C \
END
```

and the error I keep getting is

```
DB21034E  The command was processed as an SQL statement because it was not a
valid Command Line Processor command.  During SQL processing it returned:
SQL0104N  An unexpected token "CustomerID" was found following "omer  where
cus_ID =".  Expected tokens may include:  "IN <in_predicate_value>".  LINE
NUMBER=5.  SQLSTATE=42601
```

how do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You need correct delimiters, both inside the procedure to delimit each statement, and a different terminator to end the block .

You seem to be using the command-line shell, which makes it more difficult. Easier to compile the stored-procedure if you put the statements into a file (or a here-document in a shell-script) and then ask the Db2 clp to execute the file/here-document like `db2 -tvf yourfile.sql`  or
`db2 -tvf << EndHereDocument .... EndHereDocument`

Example below shows the file contents, which uses the default delimiter inside the block (semi colon ; ), and a different delimiter @ to end the block.

```
--#SET TERMINATOR @
Create procedure getCusDetails (IN CustomerID int) 
BEGIN 
    DECLARE c cursor with return for  SELECT *from customer  where cus_ID = CustomerID ;
   OPEN C ; 
END@
```

Comment: Executing files documents aren't taught in my syllabus. Is there any other way I can do without executing the file ? :(

Comment: What is your shell?  bash? or db2cmd.exe? or some other tool ?  Add this to your Question by using Edit on your question.